# Select from collection a on clause from JOIN on collection b

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: `games` and `questions`

`game` schema:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId, 
  status: 'played',
  questions: 
     [ 
       { questionId: ObjectId(questions._id) } // ref to questions collection by _id field
     ] 
 }
```

`questions` schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  text: foobar
}
```

Game could have two statuses: 'active' and 'played'.
My goal is to get all 'played' questions, means, questions, associated with games with status 'played'.

I've tried to make queries on `games` collection, tried to make queries on `questions` but none of them worked.

Some of them are:

```
db.games.aggregate([
     {$match: {status: {$ne: 'played'}}}, 
     {
         $lookup: 
           {
            from: 'questions', 
            localField: 'questions.questionId', 
            foreignField: '_id', 
            as: 'game_questions'
         }
      }, 
    {$project: {game_questions: 1}}, 
    {$unwind: {path: '$game_questions', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false}}
   ])
```

Or

```
db.questions.aggregate([
     { $project: {text: 1}}, 
     { $lookup: {
        from: 'games', 
        pipeline: [
           { $match: {status:'played' }}, 
           { $project: { status: 1 }}
        ], 
        as: 'game_data' 
      }}
])
```

**Bottom line**:
After the request I'd like to get a list with questions, where game status  is 'played'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with the data found in [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) stage

```
db.games.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "played" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "questions",
    "let": { "questions": "$questions.questionId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$questions"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "game_data"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$game_data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$game_data" }}
])
```

Or

```
db.games.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "played" }}, 
  { "$lookup": {    
    "from": "questions", 
    "localField": "questions.questionId", 
    "foreignField": "_id", 
    "as": "game_data"
  }}, 
  { "$unwind": "$game_data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$game_data" }}
])
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use the first $lookup over the second?

Comment: @Murilo `$lookup` syntax with the `pipeline` is a advanced version of older `$lookup`.  It allows you to join with multiple conditions and can allow you to use all the aggregation operators. And also I do prefer more then the older one.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)